# Does webform civicrm update contribution_recur_id when creating recurring contribution and membership?

Tags: webform-civicrm, recurring-contributions

I am looking more closely at the data structure and it appears that when the form is submitted we get an unlinked recurring contribution series and membership. Is this by design or user error in configuration?

the details - the civicrm_membership table field 'contribution_recur_id' does not seem to have the recurring ID updated from the recurring profile the webform created

Is this how people are gaining the functionality? https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur

Drupal 7 / up to date webform_civicrm and civi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does, but only when you select 0 for installments (ongoing commitment) otherwise it seems to not link the recurring properly.